# api endpoint 404 not found on NextJS 14 on the production but works fine on the local

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm building a small website using NEXT JS 14.

In my website, I have a small contact us page.

I have the following in my GetInTouch.tsx

```
<Formik
                  initialValues={{
                    fullName: "",
                    phoneNumber: "",
                    email: "",
                    message: "",
                  }}
                  validationSchema={Yup.object({
                    fullName: Yup.string().required("Required"),
                    phoneNumber: Yup.string().required("Required"),
                    email: Yup.string()
                      .email("Invalid email address")
                      .required("Required"),
                    message: Yup.string().required("Required"),
                  })}
                  onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
                    try {
                      const response = await fetch("/api/sendEmail", {
                        // Adjusted path here
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                          "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(values),
                      });

                      if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error("Failed to send email");
                      }

                      setShowSuccessMessage(true);
                      setTimeout(() => {
                        setShowSuccessMessage(false);
                      }, 5000);

                      resetForm();
                    } catch (error) {
                      console.error("Error sending email:", error);
                    } finally {
                      setSubmitting(false);
                    }
                  }}
                >
                  {(formik) => (
                    <Form >
                      <div className="pb-3">
                        <Field 
                          type="text"
                          name="fullName"
                          placeholder="Full Name"
                          className="form-input space-y-2 pt-15px lg:pt-20px w-full h-12 px-5 py-10px placeholder-white text-white"
                          style={{ backgroundColor: '#0c3863',border: '1.5px solid white'}}
                          
                         
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name="fullName"
                          component="div"
                          className="text-red-600"
                          style={{color: "red"}}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="pb-3">
                        <Field
                          type="text"
                          name="phoneNumber"
                          placeholder="Phone Number"
                          className="form-input space-y-2 pt-15px lg:pt-20px w-full h-12 px-5 py-10px placeholder-white text-white "
                          style={{ backgroundColor: '#0c3863',border: '1.5px solid white'}}
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name="phoneNumber"
                          component="div"
                          className="text-red-600"
                          style={{color: "red"}}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="pb-3">
                        <Field
                          type="email"
                          name="email"
                          placeholder="Email"
                          className="form-input space-y-2 pt-10px lg:pt-15px w-full h-12 px-5 py-10px placeholder-white text-white"
                          style={{ backgroundColor: '#0c3863',border: '1.5px solid white'}}
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name="email"
                          component="div"
                          className="text-red-600"
                          style={{color: "red"}}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="pb-3">
                        <Field
                          as="textarea"
                          name="message"
                          placeholder="Message"
                          className="form-textarea w-full pt-15px lg:pt-20px placeholder-white px-5 py-30px text-white" 
                          style={{ backgroundColor: '#0c3863',border: '1.5px solid white'}}
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name="message"
                          component="div"
                          className="text-red-600"
                          style={{color: "red"}}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <Button
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
                        className="btn"
                        size={"large"} colorTheme="blue1" uppercase
                      >
                        Enquire now
                      </Button>
                    </Form>
                    
                  )}
                </Formik>

                {showSuccessMessage && (
                  <div className="success-message flex items-center text-white text-sm font-bold py-3" >
                    Message sent successfully!
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
```

Then inside my pages/api I have sendEmail.ts file

Right now I'm using mailtrap.

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).end(); // Method Not Allowed
  }

  try {
    const { fullName, phoneNumber, email, message } = req.body;

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io',
      port: 2525,
      auth: {
        
        user: '543c2217cf0f8b',
        pass: '5rthae759cd4c0',
      },
    });

    await transporter.sendMail({
      from: 'your-email@example.com',
      to: 'support@abc.com',
      subject: 'New contact form submission',
      html: `
        <p>Full Name: ${fullName}</p>
        <p>Phone Number: ${phoneNumber}</p>
        <p>Email: ${email}</p>
        <p>Message: ${message}</p>
      `,
    });

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Email sent successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while sending the email' });
  }
}
```

When I tested this on my local, it perfectly does the form validations and send the email.

I have changed nothing on my live server.

But when ever I tried to move it to my production, it kept giving me `mydomain.com/api/sendEmail not found.`

Since I'm new to NextJS I'm struggling to find where the issue is...

Answer (score 0):

first of all can you please provide the error that you get, and my guess would be its the file name, try to double check that on the production server.

try testing if the end point exist using postman and if it does not then probably it is just the file name [sendEmail.ts].